# Array Push with key value

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

How do you add an value with an `=> $key` into an array, for example:

```
$images = array();

array_push($images, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] => $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

So the array would be like:

```
array('temporary_file_name' => 'file_name.zip');
```

But my IDE says it's invalid and would not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$images[$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']] = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

See : [removed by Mod's]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017747/need-a-function-array-push-with-keys[/removed by Mod's] and you could build a nice and dynamic multi-array function with that solution, I'm sure.

Edit: ... well ... go ahead with this then ...:

```
   $some_array[count($some_array)]=$any_value;
   /* we added a new element with the last number as key */
   $all_keys=array_keys($some_array);
   $all_values = array_values($some_array);
   $all_keys[(count($some_array)-1)]=$a_key;
   $some_array=array_combine($all_keys, $all_values);
```

Comment: You don't need to insert line breaks. Additionally, please see the formatting help within the editor.